# How to get Tweets Ids after login to twitter using android?

Tags: android, twitter, tweets

I am doing Twitter integration on my android app using Fabric, i just wanted to know that after login how to get tweet ids, so that i can show all of my Tweets on my app otherwise can anyone suggest me how to get tweets of my accounts.

```
final List<Long> tweetIds = Arrays.asList(510908133917487104L);

TweetUtils.loadTweets(tweetIds, new Callback<Tweet>() {
    @Override
    public void success(Result<Tweet> result) {
        for (Tweet tweet : result.data) {
            myLayout.addView(new TweetView(EmbeddedTweetsActivity.this, tweet));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(TwitterException exception) {

    }
});
```

Now in here i have hardcoded one tweets id "510908133917487104L", but i wanted to be dynamic after login to my account if i'll get all tweets id then i can populate dynamically.

Please kindly go through my post and suggest me some solution.

Comment: where is the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

before this method you initilize Twitter SDK then you will get session object then you call like

```
session.getUserId();
```

and pass in loadTweets()